# Call Web Service from xquery

Tags: web-services, xquery, exist-db

is it possible to call a Web Service from within an XQuery expression like you can do with User defined Table Functions in SQL?

The only thing i found for this is an extension for XQuery1.0 called a Web Services Facility.
Is there a more standardized way to call web services?

Comment: Would you care to enlighten me (and possibly others) what you see as a Web Service and in which way it relates to "User defined Table Functions in SQL". Please explain in some detail what you actually want to do.

Comment: web service as an ordinary SOAP-HTTP-Web-Service, in SQL it is possible to define user defined function that can be embedded in a SQL query and call a SOAP-HTTP WS and return the results as query variables, so the WS Call results can immediately be used within the SQL Query. For instance in a SQL INSERT in the VALUES clause i can call a Web Service and the scalar results are being used as values that are inserted into the table as VALUES. Is there a similar way to call a WS from within a XQuery

Comment: So seems like your "Web Service" is nothing more than an HTTP request, am I correct. There is an EXPath module (http://expath.org/modules/http-client/), which is implemented by multiple vendors. So it depends on which XQuery processor you are using.

Comment: well, the Web Service gets SOAP messages, and returns a SOAP message...but in fact it is a http post and get

Comment: You still haven't told us what XQuery processor you are using, it is a non-standard functionality, but available for many different processors.

Comment: i am using xquery within existdb

Comment: the question was tagged exist-db so I assumed it :-) existdb provides actually two httpclient modules, the expath version is portable, meaning the code runs on multiple xquery processors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make HTTP Requests from XQuery in eXist using the EXPath http-client library that @dirkk pointed out to you. With regards to SOAP, there is no special support for this in eXist, but that is only because you don't need anything special. SOAP messages are just XML documents and so you can construct your messages in XQuery like any other document, likewise you can process the SOAP response as it is just an XML document that comes back from the call to the http-client.